# $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$. Show that if $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ is measurable and $m(A)=0$ then $m(f(A))=0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, measure-theory

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$. Show that if $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ is measurable and $m(A)=0$ then $m(f(A))=0$ where $m(A)$ is the Lebesgue measure of A.

**My attempt:**
As the previous part of this question, I proved the result:
$`` \text{ Suppose for }f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R} \text{ There exist $L$ such that } |f(x)-f(y)|\leq L|x-y| \text{ for every }x,y\in\mathbb{R} \text{ then }m^{*}(f(A))\leq Lm^*(A)\text{ for every set }A\subset\mathbb{R}""$

So I was trying to prove that the function $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ has the Lipschitz property. But cannot see how.. May be is there a totally different way?
Appreciate your help..

Comment: Hint : apply mean value theorem.

Comment: @H_K Thank you for the comment.  so you mean.. $f(x)-f(y)=f'(c)(x-y)$ where $f'(c)=\frac{2c}{exp(c^2)}$ Then is this derivative less than $1$ or something?

Comment: The derivative $f':\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ is given by $f'(x) = \dfrac{-2x}{e^{x^2}}$. Is this function bounded? Is yes, then a bound on $f'$ can serve as the Lipschitz constant because of the MVT as you argued.